# Simple date format not formatting properly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Im writing a program that needs to be able to find the difference between two dates using java.util.date format. I'm using the SimpleDateFormat class to parse the string input but it seems to be parsing wrong. Here is my code. I appreciate any help

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date startDate = s.parse(dateField.getText()); //input is 2012/03/10
System.out.println(START_DATE);//output is Tue Jan 10 00:03:00 MST 2012
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `yyyy/MM/dd` instead of `yyyy/mm/dd`. Because `mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for month

Comment: Thanks!!that was the root of the problem

Answer (score 3):

When you print a `Date` object, you are printing a [.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) representation of the object.

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> dow mon dd
>   hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

If you want to print it in a specific format, you should use [SimpleDateFormat.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29)

So, to answer your question, if you want to simply print it in the same format as you got it, just use

`System.out.println(s.format(startDate));`

As @Namal points out below, be sure to fix your SimpleDateFormat to use the correct format. `mm` represents minutes. `MM` represents months.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 lines of code are independent of each other. You create a SimpleDateFormat object named s, then use the javaDate object to parse the string, then print the object START_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date startDate = new Date();
System.out.println(s.format(startDate));
```

outputs

```
Thu Mar 08 15:23:57 EST 2012
```

Comment: to expand on that question, what if i have a date in format:       "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" could i apply the sdf above to it?

Comment: One pattern per `SimpleDateFormat` instance. Also note that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. It's implementation is batsh*t crazy.

Comment: my question is: I have a new java date that the system outputs as:        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" and one the end user inputs as yyyy/mm/dd and i was able to fix the second one with your advice but if i try to format the timestamp with the original sdf then the output is incorrect. I get: 2012/23/07 for today's timestamp